# How to configure SWRevealViewController/PKRevealController/etc to handle orientation and presentation changes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am using `SWRevealViewController` (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to handle switching between two controllers, a "front" and a "rear".

The front controller is a `UINavigationController` and the rear controller is just a plain `UIViewController` that displays a list of menu items. The front `UINavigationController` pushes an instance of a view controller named `FrontViewController`. The rear `UIViewController` is an instance of `RearViewController`. The instance of `SWRevealViewController` is set as the root view controller once it is configured with the front and rear controllers, the `delegate` property of the reveal controller is set to the app delegate itself.

In both `FrontViewController` and `RearViewController` I am overriding `shouldAutorotate` and returning NO as well as overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`.

However the app auto rotates and goes into Landscape while these two views are displaying when I rotate the device.

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` seems to only be invoked in `FrontViewController` but the value is not honored and the device rotates into landscape orientation.

I can't simply set the entire app to Portrait either because I have other detail views that I do want to support Landscape (movie player, etc).

How can I get `SWRevealViewController` working so I can restrict the app to Portrait in certain child views of the controller?

I have also noticed that the presentation changes are not being honored as well.  In `RearViewController` I am overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` to return `YES` but this method is never invoked.  Similarly in `FrontViewController` I am overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` to return `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` but this method is never called either.

I have `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to `YES` in my plist.

UPDATE:

I have tried to use `PKRevealController` as suggested in the comments but the behavior is exactly the same. Supported orientations and status bar styles are completely ignore. `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on `FrontViewController` is the only override invoked but the return value of `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` is not honored.

UPDATE 2:

I'm thinking that this is simply a limitation of these controls and they pretty much expect the support orientations to be the same throughout the application.  I did however try `MFSideMenu` (https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) and it seems to handle supported orientations in different child views exactly as you would expect it to. I still don't have the status bar visibility and styles working, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you looked at PKRevealController? https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

Comment: I checked it out and it actually looks like a better library, however the same exact problem persists.  It's like the reveal controller overrides the orientation setups in the rest of the views in the app.  I'm probably just going to make everything support Landscape but it would be nice to know why this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being to subclass `PKRevealController` and override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `shouldAutorotate`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`, `prefersStatusBarHidden`, and `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

While `MFSideMenu` did this for orientation it did not support status bar configurations. I also ran into a major bug with `MFSideMenu` that prevented me from using it in my project.

I made each method I override return a value from the appropriate controller depending on the circumstance. In the case orientation I return the value from `self.frontViewController.topViewController` (since I am using a UINavigation controller). Status bar style and visibility came from either `self.frontViewController` or `self.leftViewController` depending on the current state.

The same solution probably would have worked for `SWRevealViewController` as well but I preferred the API design of `PKRevealController`.

I figured subclassing would work from the beginning but I assumed that such a common scenario would be handled in the configuration of these controls.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this while not avoiding SWRevealViewController: Inside of it there is implemented method supportedInterfaceOrientations, which needs to be edited. I have done this:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
UINavigationController* frontNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.frontViewController;
if ([frontNavigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[VCgallery class]]) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

All my viewControllers are portrait only except those that are of class VCgallery, which can be both portrait and lanscape.